# how can give position for lightbox

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making lightbox and i try to make position but it doesn't working if i add div id. i added jquery and javascript 
i want to give position how can i make ?

```
  <div id="photos">
    <style type="text/css">
      #photos {
        position: absolute;
      }

      #photos ul li {
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-top: 80px;
      }
    </style>

    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="img/example.png" data-lightbox="example.png" data-title="photos title"><img src="img/example.png" width="100" height="110" /></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: To select id use `#`, to select class use `.` -- So `<div id="photos">` will be selected with `#photos`,  `<div class="photos">` will be selected with `.photos`

Comment: Post some more of your code so We could understand what you really are doing. I'm seeing a lot of problems so far.

Comment: it doesn't working currently

Answer (score 0):

For Positioning an element in CSS We have:

```
#photos{                    // Select element Which have the ID of photos
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;            // Move this element to left up to 120 PX;
    top: 120px;             // From top Move this element up to 120 PX;
}
```

FYI: `<style>` tags are kept in `head` of you page not after the element itself.

good luck:)

Answer (score 0):

A lightbox is just a regular DIV structure that has been styled `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` to remove it from the normal HTML flow. It is then hidden, and displayed when desired upon a button click or other detectable event (mouseover, ajax.done, etc).

Since a lightbox is just a normal div, you can stick new stuff into the lightbox/div *on the fly* using `$('#divID').html('<tag>Your HTML here</tag>')` or `.append()` or `.text()` etc.

First get your project working with a "lightbox" that is not hidden, then add `display:none` to the CSS for the lightbox HTML's top container *e.g. `<div id="lightbox">` in my example code* and use the `.show() / .hide()` etc commands to reveal the lightbox when desired.

```js
$('#btnClickMe').click(function(){
  $('#photos').fadeIn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
  #photos {position: absolute;display:none;}
  #photos ul li {padding-left: 20px;padding-top: 80px;}
</style>

<div id="photos">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-lightbox="example.png" data-title="photos title"><img src="http://placeimg.com/100/110/animals" width="100" height="110" /></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button id="btnClickMe">Click Me</button>
```

Here is another example of a self-rolled lightbox:

```js
/* js/jQuery */
$(document).ready(function(){
  
$('button').click(function(){
  $('#lightbox').html('This is a lightbox').fadeIn();
});

$('#lightbox').click(function(){
  $(this).fadeOut();
});
  
}); //END document.ready
```

```css
/* CSS */
#myBody{padding:120px;font-size:2rem;background:palegreen;}

#lightbox{position:absolute;top:15%;left:10%;width:80%;height:60%;font-size:5rem;color:orange;text-align:center;background:black;opacity:0.8;display:none;}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Display lightbox</button>

<div id="myBody">This is my normal page content</div>

<div id="lightbox"></div>
```